# How insert multiline text into a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox` that displays text saved in RTF. I've got a contextual menu that add some multi lines text at the caret position using this code

```
var text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2"
richTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(text);
```

It displays as I expect

```
Line1
Line2
```

When I save and reload the text (saved in RTF), it displays as this:

```
Line1Line2
```

When I look in the RTF code, it is saved without the CR and LF...

Why my CR/LF vanished? What is the solution to insert multi line text at the caret position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do:

```
var text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2"
richTextBox.Control.Selection.Text = text;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. It helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

Set RichTextBox.AcceptsReturn to True

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f044f15b-48a4-485c-91c0-07a0828acb98/acceptsreturn-in-a-wpf-richtextbox